# PHP header function is not working correctly after record update

Tags: php

Update Query is like This i am getting success in update record but it's not redirect in page when records updated whole text box value is fill in text box
i want to redirect user on current page but not with last updated value i want to redirect on blank page.

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $vepariId > 0)
        {
          $update = "UPDATE vepari
                        SET partyId = ".$_REQUEST['partyId'].",
                            vDate = '".$vDate."',
                            veTransType = '".$_REQUEST['veTransType']."',
                            vParti = '".$_REQUEST['vParti']."',
                            vRate = ".$_REQUEST['vRate'].",
                            vDiff = '".$_REQUEST['vDiff']."',
                            vDiffAmt = ".$_REQUEST['vDiffAmt'].",
                            vTotal = ".$_REQUEST['vTotal'].",
                            vTax = ".$_REQUEST['vTax'].",
                            vkg = ".$_REQUEST['vkg'].",
                            vTotalAmt = ".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
          $updateRes= mysql_query($update);
          if($updateRes)
          {
            if($veTransType == 'A')
            {
              $update = "UPDATE mcx 
                          SET 
                          partyId = ".$partyId.",
                          transDate = '".$vDate."',
                          transType = 'J',
                          rate = '".$_REQUEST['vRate']."',
                          kg = '".$_REQUEST['vkg']."',
                          totalAmt = '".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."'
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
              $updateRes = mysql_query($update);
              if(!$updateRes)
              {
                 echo "Mcx Update Fail";
              }
            }
            else
            {
              $update = "UPDATE mcx 
                          SET 
                          partyId = ".$partyId.",
                          transDate = '".$vDate."',
                          transType = 'A',
                          rate = '".$_REQUEST['vRate']."',
                          kg = '".$_REQUEST['vkg']."',
                          totalAmt = '".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."'
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
              $updateRes = mysql_query($update);    
              if(!$updateRes)
              {
                 echo "Mcx Aavak Update Fail";
              }
              else
              {
                header("Location:vepari.php");
              } 
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: try putting `exit;` just after your `header()` function..

Comment: This seems veeeeery injection-prone...

Comment: Still Same Result @NishantSolanki

Comment: Than what is best way for it @Rasclatt

Comment: 1) You should not be using the `mysql_` functions anymore 2) if you do, you should be escaping the direct input (`$_REQUEST['xxx']`) 3) You should be using `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared and bound statements.

Comment: where is your `header()` redirect in first if condition?? `(i.e if($veTransType == 'A'))`

Comment: me forget that thanks bro now working properly @NishantSolanki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have made some modifications please have a look on it. please keep it in mind that when you use echo before header then it will cause issue it is better to use javascript redirection like window.location.href when you printing something in page.

```html
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $vepariId > 0)
        {
          $update = "UPDATE vepari
                        SET partyId = ".$_REQUEST['partyId'].",
                            vDate = '".$vDate."',
                            veTransType = '".$_REQUEST['veTransType']."',
                            vParti = '".$_REQUEST['vParti']."',
                            vRate = ".$_REQUEST['vRate'].",
                            vDiff = '".$_REQUEST['vDiff']."',
                            vDiffAmt = ".$_REQUEST['vDiffAmt'].",
                            vTotal = ".$_REQUEST['vTotal'].",
                            vTax = ".$_REQUEST['vTax'].",
                            vkg = ".$_REQUEST['vkg'].",
                            vTotalAmt = ".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
          $updateRes= mysql_query($update);
          if($updateRes)
          {
            if($veTransType == 'A')
            {
              $update = "UPDATE mcx 
                          SET 
                          partyId = ".$partyId.",
                          transDate = '".$vDate."',
                          transType = 'J',
                          rate = '".$_REQUEST['vRate']."',
                          kg = '".$_REQUEST['vkg']."',
                          totalAmt = '".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."'
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
              $updateRes = mysql_query($update);
              if(!$updateRes)
              {
                 echo "Mcx Update Fail";
                exit;
              }
            }
            else
            {
              $update = "UPDATE mcx 
                          SET 
                          partyId = ".$partyId.",
                          transDate = '".$vDate."',
                          transType = 'A',
                          rate = '".$_REQUEST['vRate']."',
                          kg = '".$_REQUEST['vkg']."',
                          totalAmt = '".$_REQUEST['vTotalAmt']."'
                        WHERE vepariId = ".$vepariId;
              $updateRes = mysql_query($update);    
              if(!$updateRes)
              {
                 echo "Mcx Aavak Update Fail";
                 exit;
              }
              else
              {
                header("Location:vepari.php");
              } 
            }
          }
        }
```